# Subtract y-scrollbar width and x-scrollbar height from body width and height respectively in webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My webpage has centered header, content and footer divs, each with a width of 900px.

(The only other possibly relevant information I can provide about the header, content and footer is that the header has fixed positioning, the content is relatively positioned and the footer is absolutely positioned. However, I am not sure if this information will be relevant to the solution.)

I am using the following CSS media query:

```
/* If screen width is less than or equal to 900px (e.g.: tablet, mobile) ... */
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    /* Scale header, content and footer width */
    #header, #content, #footer { width: 100%; }
}
```

to begin scaling these divs down with the page when the page width becomes less than their default widths. I want the scale down to be seamless across all browsers, however, I am presented with a problem because webkit browsers calculate the y and x scrollbars width in the page width. This makes the scrollbar cover the divs at certain widths, and makes the scale down occur late.

I would like a JQuery solution to calculate and subtract the y-scrollbar width and x-scrollbar height from the CSS body width and height respectively in webkit browsers, to account for how webkit browsers include the scrollbar in the width and height of the page, so that my CSS media queries to rescale the body of the page to fit the viewing area works the same across all browsers.

I am not interested in alternative solutions such as making the scrollbars always present to make scaling down always work the same in webkit browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using JavaScript do detect if your HTML body is larger than the window in both horizontal and vertical directions. If they exceed the window, there is a scrollbar. You can then add a padding to the body to accomodate for this.

I believe scrollbars have a width of about 15px, but that should be easy to find.

```
// Check if body height is higher than window height :)
if ($("body").height() > $(window).height()) {
    alert("Vertical Scrollbar! D:");
}

// Check if body width is higher than window width :)
if ($("body").width() > $(window).width()) {
    alert("Horizontal Scrollbar! D:<");
}
```

You can use to above code to detect both value. Placing these in a listener for window resizes will make sure that all parameters are reevaluated whenever necesary.

UPDATE:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    // Check if body height is higher than window height :)
    if ($("body").height() > $(window).height()) {
        $('body').css('padding-bottom', '15px');
    } else {
        $('body').css('padding-bottom', '0');
    }

    // Check if body width is higher than window width :)
    if ($("body").width() > $(window).width()) {
        $('body').css('padding-right', '15px');
    } else {
        $('body').css('padding-right', '0');
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

EXTRA:

In case the scrollbar dimensions are different per browser, you could simply make a CSS class with the browser appropriate dimensions and apply it by calling:

```
$('body').addClass('<CLASSNAME>');
```

and

```
$('body').removeClass('<CLASSNAME>');
```

Instead of set and unsetting the padding on the body.

Comment: Good idea and sounds like a solid algorithm, but I am not skilled enough in JQuery syntax yet to do this.

Comment: I updated my answer to be more complete for your specific problem :) hope this solves it. You may have to check what the exact width and height for a scrollbar is, and hopefully it doesn't differ per browser.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this just displaces the divs by 15 pixels and doesn't change scrollbars effect on the width. I guess I'll look into it more and use the syntax as a basis for my fix though.